# Reading very big XML file (4GB) into a char* for parsing (Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)

Tags: c, xml, parsing, pointers, segmentation-fault

Here i am trying to read a very big XML file into a char*, but i am getting the following Error:

(Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s))

It is pointing to the line-> size= fread(result,sizeof(char),size,file);

I am using Valgrind for debugging the Segmentation fault. Help are very much appreciated

EDIT:
I just ran a test and found out that result is actually pointing to NULL meaning it cannot allocate that much. What am i supposed to do then ?

```
// Converts XML file to Char*
char* XMLtoString(char* path){
    FILE* file;
    unsigned long long size;
    char* result;

    file = fopen(path,"r");
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);  
    size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET);
    result = (char*)malloc((sizeof(char)*size)+1);
    size = fread(result,sizeof(char),size,file);
    result[size] = '\0';
    fclose(file);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Under many systems, 4GB is more than it's possible for `malloc` to return.

Comment: You are trying to allocate 4gb chunk with that malloc, are you sure that your system can actually do that for you? it might return whatever malloc returns if it's unable to allocate (-1 or null, i would guess) and then you are converting that to a pointer, which will point to who knows where.

Comment: First you need to check whether `malloc` succeeded. `if(result == NULL) {fprintf(stderr, "not enough memory!\n"); exit(1); }`

Comment: There is no test if the file opened, no test if malloc failed, not confirmation print of the size... Just post a question on SO and someone will help out...

Comment: These days, the usual approach to processing a file that big involves `mmap`.

Comment: suspect your program is being compiled as 32-bit where maximum memory is about 3GB.

Comment: I just ran a test and found out that result is actually pointing to NULL meaning it cannot allocate that much. What am i supposed to do then ?

Comment: 1. Buy more memory.  2. Buy a newer, 64-bit machine.  3. Rethink your approach.

Comment: My computer is a 64 bit machine and i have 16 gb Ram. Maybe because i am launching it in a Virtual box machine ubuntu ?

Comment: Try running the command `uname -m`.  If it prints "i686" your VM is 32 bits.  If it prints "x86_64" your VM is 64 bits, and there's some small hope that your approach might work.

Comment: Just solved it by allocating more than 5 GB in Base memmory of the virtual machine. Thanks for the help !

Comment: In general, there are two or three different ways of parsing data structures such as XML. (1) Read it all into memory, then parse it. (2) Read and parse it at the same time.  And then there's a second degree of variability: as you parse it, you can either create an in-memory data structure corresponding to the complete, hierarchical structure of the entire input file (the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) model), or do you process it as you parse it, extracting just the information you're looking for (the [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) model)?

Comment: Obviously, the bigger your XML file is, the more advantageous it is to parse-as-you-read, and process-as-you-parse.  Trying to read everything, then parse everything, then process, can be extremely wasteful.  (Although, it must be said, it may be the easiest or most convenient or most obvious way of doing it, and programmer time matters, too.)

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was the Base Memmory for my Virtual Machine Ubuntu was 2 GB and I changed it to 10 and now its working. Thanks everyone for the help!